# Access violation for local variable but not for global one of same type

Tags: memory-management, global, local, pascal

I have two versions of the same function, one uses a global queue object the other a local queue object. The one with the local one throws an memory access error:

version 1:

```
procedure breadth_first_traversal(var t : tree);
var
   cre :  elementPtr;
   crt : treePtr;
begin
   queue_enqueue(tq, t);
   while not queue_empty(tq) do
   begin
      cre := queue_dequeue(tq);
      crt := cre^.load;
      writeln(crt^.load);
      if assigned(crt^.lt) then
      begin
     queue_enqueue(tq, crt^.lt^);
      end;
      if assigned(crt^.rt) then
      begin
     queue_enqueue(tq, crt^.rt^);
      end;
   end;
end;
```

version 2:

```
procedure breadth_first_traversal(var t : tree);
var
   tree_queue   : queue;
   cre :  elementPtr;
   crt : treePtr;
begin
   queue_enqueue(tree_queue, t);
   while not queue_empty(tree_queue) do
   begin
      cre := queue_dequeue(tree_queue);
      crt := cre^.load;
      writeln(crt^.load);
      if assigned(crt^.lt) then
      begin
     queue_enqueue(tree_queue, crt^.lt^);
      end;
      if assigned(crt^.rt) then
      begin
     queue_enqueue(tree_queue, crt^.rt^);
      end;
   end;
end;
```

throwing this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred at $000000000040037A :
EAccessViolation : Access violation
  $000000000040037A
  $0000000000400425
  $0000000000400590
```

Why would version 1 using the global variable `tq` which has the same type as `tree_queue` work and version 2 not??

Comment: If queue is a record, in the local version its fields have undefined values. In general local variables are not initialized. Depending on what queue_enqueue or others doing an access violation may occur. As you can see the code is nowhere near providing information. Either do some debugging or provide an MCVE.

Comment: I explained in your last question that local variables are not initialized, and yet you again use an uninitialized local variable in this code. If you're not going to read the information we're providing, what's the point of asking in the first place?

Comment: maybe I am just stupid like that and need a little longer to sort stuff out in my head, resulting in me unknowingly asking the same thing twice, while on the surface it looked like a different problem to me.

Comment: Hard to tell from the code you've shown. `queue_dequeue(tq)` returns a pointer that you reference, so you'd need to show `queue_dequeue` implementation to see what it's up to. `crt^.lt^` is passed to `queue_enqueue`, so we'd need to see how your data structure was created to tell if the pointer is valid, or at least see if `queue_enqueue` checks for a valid pointer.